# Runnable Jar file not finding bundled resources

Tags: eclipse, jar, maven-3, vert.x

I have a simple web server (implemented in Vertx) which serves static content composed of HTML, CSS, and Javascript files. I have developed this server in the latest Eclipse IDE.

The server works well in the development environment, but when I generate a runnable Jar file, the jar file fails to "find" the
web pages.

The Vertx Web code that I am using is pretty straightforward. I am using the static content method as provided on the Vertx Web documentation:

```
  HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();
  
  Router router = Router.router(vertx);
  
  router.route(HttpMethod.GET,"/*").handler(StaticHandler.create(".").setIndexPage("index.html"));
  
  server.requestHandler(router);
  
  server.listen(8099,result->{
     if(result.succeeded())
        log.info("Main Server has started! Listening on Port "+server.actualPort());
     else if(result.failed())
        log.error("Main Server start FAILED. Reason: "+result.cause());
  });
```

The directory structure of my project is below:

```
  testmain
  |
  --src
  | |
  | --<package net.test.app>
  |   |
  |   --TestServer.java
  |
  --resources
    |
    --index.html
    |
    -- sheet.css
    |
    --script.js
```

I generate the runnable Jar using the usual method: Export->Runnable Jar File. In the export dialog, I specify the TestServer application and destination Jar, and I select "Extract required libraries into generated jar".

Examining the contents of the runnable Jar file using 7-Zip, I see that all necessary class files, libraries, and static resources are in the Jar file. Unfortunately, when I run the application, the files cannot be found. The only way to make the application find them is to copy them into the same folder as the jar file/ Even then, the Javascript file isn't being found.

I am sure that there is a way to configure the runnable Jar so that the application will look within the jar file for its resources, because other applications (servlet- based or Spring Boot applications) are packaged so that their runnables are self- contained. Unfortunately, neither the Eclipse documentation nor any of the pages describing runnable Jars address this issue.

Those that talk about using resources within a runnable suggest changing the code that accesses the files so that it finds them on the classpath. This is good, but because I am using Vertx web to access the static files, rewriting the code for reading them is not an option.

Is there a way to configure my runnable Jar so that it looks within the jar for its resources? Or failing that, is there a way to make Vertx access them from within the Jar?

Comment: If you generated the project using the [vert.x starter](https://start.vertx.io/), you can check the readme for how to package the application using maven. The jar that gets generated that way will be runnable by default.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the starter for me. I hadn't known about it. Unfortunately, the readme doesn't really tell me anything about including resources in the jar. It only give pointers to the Vert.x documentation (which says nothing about the starter!), a Stack Overflow search page, and a couple of places that I have no access to. Can you or anyone else point me to some actual documentation for the starter?

Comment: I figured out the starter and packaged the jar file as completely as I was able to figure out. The jar file still does not find the packaged resources.

Comment: Can you try putting the file in `webroot` and then creating the statichandler without "."?

Comment: Selim: I do not understand your question. What is the statichandler you are referring to? I am not using it to get the web pages.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I see a `StaticHandler` in your code above :-)

Comment: OOPS! *That* StaticHandler! Sorry, I was a little muddled when I read your suggestion.